# Error: Cannot call process.nextTick from within a sync test ,when making a POST request

Tags: angular, protractor

I am testing a module and I would like to store a temporary data in the database  but when I used the service to make the request I got the following error :

> Cannot call process.nextTick from within a sync test.

I did not find anything related on the internet .

Test.e2e-spec.ts

```
import {browser, by, element} from 'protractor';
import {Player} from '../src/myapp';
import {Myservice} from '../src/myservices';
import {Mysecondservice} from '../src/myservices';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';

}

describe('your first protractor test', () => {
    let player: Player;
    let mysecondservice: Mysecondservice ;
    let EC;

    beforeAll(() => {
        EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;
        player= new Player();

        player.firstName = 'fname';
        player.lastName = 'lname';
        player.email = 'ss@gmail.com';
        browser.get('/');

    });

    it('should load a page and verify the url', fakeAsync(() => {
        const SignInButton = element(by.buttonText('Sign in'));
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(SignInButton), 4000, 'waiting for feed button to be clickable');
        mysercondservice.addPlayer(player);
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + 'login');
    }));

    });
```

Mysecondservice works perfectly with the api but here when making the request it gives the showed error .

Comment: Why do you use `fakeAsync` instead of the `async/await`?

Comment: The testing book recommended using ```fakeAsync```  , ```async/await```  gives the same error